# The word 'fragile'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can I use the word 'fragile' in this sentence?

**He died of a heart attack during a fragile operation.**

Thank you for answering in advance.

Comment: Are you using 'fragile' to mean 'delicate'?

Comment: fragile - easily broken. Would you say "an easily broken operation"?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I wanted to use this word to mean such as 'careless, negligent, inattentive'. Is it possible to use this word? Or for any meaning, is "fragile poeration" strange?

Comment: No, you cannot use _fragile_ in that sense. Kumar's answer was downvoted because people didn't realise that that was indeed what you were trying to say. You could use something like _badly managed_ if you didn't want to be quite so blunt.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reckon 'botched' will be a better word than fragile.

Regards

Comment: The use of "botched" implies blame on the part of the surgical team and there is nothing in the original question to infer that this is the case.

Comment: I concur with @KillingTime. The term "botched" would not be acceptable unless you are trying to point the finger at the surgeon. As above, the word "delicate" would be much better.

Comment: Bungled is another option. So is delicate. A person or an art object may be fragile, but not an operation.